# When I ssh into the Sandbox, and I simply type hive in the shell, I get this output inside the stderr

Tags: shell, hadoop, ssh, hive

When I ssh into the Sandbox, and I simply type hive in the shell, I get this output inside the stderr:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.4.2-2-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Comment: Thanks  for  answer  i  donot  see  hive. I use  of  sandbox 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

That is not error. You can safely ignore it

If you see `hive>` then it worked.

Though, if you are using recent versions of the sandbox, I think you should [use `beeline` instead](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/)